# Почему оператор << для ostream не перегружен для контейнеров?

Tags: c++, c++11

Почему оператор `<<` для `ostream` не перегружен для контейнеров, таких как `vector`, `set`, `map`?

И если есть проблемы с перегрузкой оператора `<<` для `ostream`, то почему бы не добавить функцию `print` или `print_container`, которая бы могла выводить контейнеры.

Спрашиваю больше из-за любопытства и из-за того, что такую мелочь приходится реализовывать самому. Притом, что во многих других языках выводить контейнеры не составляет труда.

Comment: Потому что это - не "другие языки" :)

Comment: Потому что написать такой вывод - секундное дело... А как именно выводить тот же вектор - вопрос спорный. Стандарт же - закон: что написано пером, хрен потом вырубишь... И тут нельзя ошибиться.

Comment: Да, реализация подобных штук - слишком opinion-based =)

Comment: Насколько в плюсовую систему типов вписывается тот факт, что ключи и/или значения могут не иметь строкового представления и потому не поддаваться выводу?

Comment: @D-side, `<<` для `ostream`, вроде, может выводить все примитивные типы. Что может не поддаваться выводу?

Comment: @pank типы не из примитивных, например.

Comment: @D-side, вы о тех, что пользователь определит? Но тут само собой разумеется придется перегружать `<<` для своего типа.

Comment: @pank вот меня и беспокоит, что пользователь может оказаться вынужден определять нафиг не нужный ему метод исключительно чтобы удовлетворить требованиям контейнеров. Выводимость контейнеров не забота контейнеров (в общем случае). Их задача хранить, искать и перебирать.

Comment: @D-side, с чего вы взяли, что контейнер должен иметь свойство выводится на печать. Наоборот оператор `<<` должен уметь выводить контейнеры из стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: @pank затем, что type safety потребует у всех контейнеров из стандартной библиотеки иметь свойство выводиться на печать, нет? В этом и состоял мой встречный вопрос, можно ли это комфортно уместить в плюсовую систему типов.

Comment: `Притом, что во многих других языках выводить контейнеры не составляет труда.` Известная тема что программисты с++ с легкостью решают те задачи, о которых программисты Delphi даже не в курсе ;)

Comment: На самом деле эта проблема давно решена - http://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/ (там есть один h файл, который нужно подключить)

Comment: @KoVadim Жуть. Использовать в версии C++11 этот фокус с `struct sfinae_base
        {
            using yes = char;
            using no  = yes[2];
        };`?... :(

Comment: для особых ценителей там есть версия от Stephan T Lavavej.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Скажите, как правильно выводить `vector<int>` - через запятую? с фиксированной шириной поля? Может, все брать в скобки?

А `vector<string>` - строки нужно брать в кавычки? или нет?

А `list<double>` - с какой именно точностью и в каком формате выводить?

Заметим, это вы решаете не для себя, а **для всех** программистов на C++...

Вы готовы к таким holy wars?

А написать свой вывод - секундное же дело. Ну, в крайнем случае напишите 
`copy(c.begin(),c.end(),ostream_iterator<int>(cout,","))` :-)

*"По-моему, так"* (с) Пух

Comment: Для `list<double>` ведь есть `fixed` и `setprecision`, а вот с вектором строк действительно проблема, но и тут можно выкрутится. Можно добавить флаг `quotes`, который будет обрамлять строку в кавычки, а символы `"` внутри строки заменять на `\"`. Хотя это уменьшит быстродействие... С вектором строк действительно проблема.

Comment: А выделить массив в хипе секундное дело, а строки сравнить с помощью `strcmp` секундное? Да что там! Кому-то парсер написать секундное дело или буферизацию с кэшированием. Поэтому "секундное дело" не аргумент. И ваш пример не секундный совсем. А ТС дело говорит.

Comment: @Cerbo а вы писали это дольше? Ну или в крайнем случае `for  (auto& x : c) cout << c <<","`

Comment: @pavel У вас запятая будет выводится после последнего элемента, там нужно обработку крайних элементов делать чтобы провильно запятую выводить. В нормальной системе должно быть `cout << container`.

Comment: "Скажите, как правильно выводить vector<int> - через запятую? " - почему то в других языках эта проблема не возникает.

Comment: @KoVadim, поддерживаю! Если уж это и действительно проблема, то всегда можно добавить флаги и переменные, для кастомизиции вывода.

Comment: И сделать убогого монстра... Вы никогда не задумывались, почему, собственно, в библиотеке C++ нет массы функций, которые есть в других языках? :) Понимаете... вы или программист на C++, и тогда у вас скорее появятся вопросы - какого черта в стандартную библиотеку воткнули так много лишнего? или вы программист, грубо говоря, на Java, и тогда у вас вопросы - почему нет отдельной функции для удаления из слова всех гласных букв, - ведь препод задал именно это задание! Это просто мировоззрение... И, кстати, заметьте - какие уже holy wars пошли. А вы еще хотите это в стандарт засунуть... :)

Comment: @Harry, если Вы считаете, что если чего-то нет в стандартной библиотеке, то это потому, что было принято взвешенное решение, это туда не помещать, то Вы глубоко заблуждаетесь(исключая некоторые частные случаи, коих ничтожно малое количество).

Comment: @ixSci Не вам и не в обиду будь сказано, но... Где-то было сказано, что человек охотно признает свою неквалифицированность в том или ином вопросе, но все считают себя гениями в политике, любви и войне, кажется... Я бы добавил - те, кто немного научились программировать, тоже считают, что уж они бы сделали язык куда лучше Страуструпа, а стандарт написали бы куда лучше принятого... Отсюда и все эти holy wars. Еще раз - это не к вам, так, ваш комментарий натолкнул на мысли...

Comment: "list<double> - с какой именно точностью и в каком формате выводить?" а с обычным double почему то проблем не возникает:) А тут сразу проблема.

Comment: @Harry, без таких людей не было бы развития и всё бы давно умерло. Благо в комитете понимают всю убогость и недоразвитость стандартной библиотеки и активно работают надо наполнением оной. Не нужно пытаться оправдывать отсутствие удобных средств разработки, нужно добавлять их. Вот Вы пишите, что вывести вектор  можно одной строкой, но для этой строки нужно ещё и заголовок подключить. Да и писать эту строку не хочется, когда вывод вектора, как правило, нужен в целях отладки или проверки. Отсутствие таких банальных инструментов в библиотеке очень часто расстраивает.

Comment: @ixSci Не думаю. Но, как в любой holy wars, здесь все равно не может быть победителя. Так что я завязываю с этой бесполезной дискуссией (сестра, ключи телевизор погромче! :)) Просто для меня все эти выяснения сродни постоянно появляющимся здесь темам **компилятор неверно работает**, **ошибка в функции имярек стандартной библиотеки** и иже с ними, где, как потом выясняется, программист просто допустил с десяток ошибок...

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, контейнеры состоят из многих элементов, поэтому не ясно, в каком формате выводить элементы контейнера. Например, можно выводить каждый элемент на новой строке. Можно выводить все элементы на одной строке через пробел. А можно выводить все элементы на одной строке через запятую или точку с запятой и т.д.

Во-вторых, контейнеры могут содержать не только фундаментальные типы, но и созданные пользователем типы. В этом случае вообще невозможно заранее предугадать, как должен выглядеть вывод элементов контейнера.

Поэтому на самом деле все сводится к перегрузке оператора для вывода самих элементов контейнера. Ответственность за перегрузку оператора для созданных пользователем типов лежит на пользователе. Имея такой перегруженный оператор, не составляет труда вывести все элементы контейнера. Причем таких смособов существует несколько: вы можете использовать стандартные алгоритмы, как, например, `std::copy`, `std::copy_if` и другие. Либо можете использовать обычные циклы: `for`, `while`, `do-while`. Либо использовать цикл на основе диапазона. Причем вы можете также задавать условия, по которым будут отбираться элементы для вывода из контейнера.

Что касается других языков, то обычно этот вопрос решается за счет того, что все объекты наследуются от одного базового объекта, который имеет виртуальную (или не виртуальную) функцию `toString` (или `ToString`). То есть любой объект, который создается пользователем, уже имеет по умолчанию функцию вывода в поток. Или же создаваемые новые объекты уже имеют некоторый минимальный интерфейс, куда входит и функция преобразования объекта к строке.

В C++ нет единого объекта, от которого произошли все другие объекты, а потому нет заранее предопределенной функции преобразования произвольного объекта к строке, которую можно вывести в поток.

Comment: Про разные типы в контейнерах вы, надеюсь, шутите. Это все рулится шаблонами.

Comment: @Cerbo И как это "рулится шаблонами", когда вы даже не можете знать заранее, какие члены данных есть у пользовательского типа?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, о том должны ли и как выводится *свои* типы данных программист должен беспокоится *сам*.

Comment: @pank У меня это и написано в ответе.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Вы написали "заранее вообще не возвожно предугадать", так вот это, мягко говоря, неправда. Шаблоны могут "знать" типы. Если у вас тип пользовательский без перегрузки `<<` или к строке он не приводится например, то компилятор честно должен ругнуться "не могу" и все. Нет никаких препятствий в Си++ чтобы так сделать.

Comment: @Cerbo  Я написал в ответе довольно ясно, что "все сводится к перегрузке оператора для вывода самих элементов контейнера".

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Так я об этом вам и говорю, что у вас противоречие. С одной стороны у вас "вообще не возможно предугадать", а с другой "все сводится". Если вы не можете что-то предугадать, то свести к чему-то это никак не возможно. Если свести всетаки можно, то что мешает реализовать оператор `<<` для контейнеров? Ничего! Следовательно вы обосновываете то, что не имеет обоснования.

Answer (score 3):

Технически проблем никаких нет. Для разделителей, скобок и прочих украшений ничего не мешает добавить такие же модификаторы как для интегральных типов. Релизация могла бы выглядеть так:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator << (        std::ostream   & printer
                            , const std::vector<T> & items  )
{
    printer << std::begin_scope();
    std::copy(  items.begin()
              , items.end  ()
              , std::ostream_iterator<T>(  printer
                                         , std::delimeter())
             );
    printer << std::end_scope();
    return printer;
}
```

В части ввода/вывода, воспроизвели функционал стандартной библиотеки Си только на Си++ :) Предпологается что программист сам как ему надо руками напишет.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, проблема реализации вывода в поток у стандартных контейнеров гораздо более серьезная, чем выбор формата вывода и сепораторов. Допустим оператор << у контейнеров STL реализован. Разумеется, самое простое, что можно придумать - он обходит все айтемы и помещать их в выходной поток тем же оператором <<. Отсюда резонное требования ко всем типам, используемых в контейнерах - наличие оператора вывода в поток. Согласитесь, не очень гибко

Comment: Ну как бы все гибко http://ideone.com/yAigAh

Comment: Теперь поместите в вектор пользовательский тип - простая структура из одного поля подойдет вполне, и посмотрите, скомпилируется Ваш код или нет

Comment: конечно скомпоилируется.

Comment: Наверное, вы шутите. У вашей структуры foo нет оператора вывода в поток, это неприменно приведет к ошибке компиляции

Comment: @KoVadim поместите вектор x в выходной поток

Comment: в этом случае конечно компилятор скажет, что нужно реализовать недостающий оператор. Но Вы же пишете о том, что "резонное требования ко всем типам, используемых в контейнерах - наличие оператора вывода в поток". foo используется в контейнере? да, нужен оператор вывода? нет, пока я не захочу вывести. Но в этом случае компилятор не знает, как вывести и спрашивает меня (хотя по хорошему, у него есть предостаточно информации, что бы это сделать).

Comment: @KoVadim абсолютно верно. Не совсем корректно написал о "всех типах, используемых в контейнерах". Конечно, требование к тем типам контейнеров, которые помещаем в выходной поток, согласно исходному вопросу